# Sort by priority using Doubly linked list

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort, doubly-linked-list

I'm stuck here, anyone can help me out to solve this.

```
                Integer Personid = rs.getInt("Personid");
                String FirstName = rs.getString("FirstName");
                String LastName = rs.getString("LastName");
                String DateOfArrival = rs.getString("DateOfArrival");
                String PassportNumber = rs.getString("PassportNumber");
                String PriorityLevel = rs.getString("PriorityLevel");
                PriorityNumber = rs.getString("PriorityNumber");

                  ArrayList<String>  queue = new ArrayList<String>();

                   queue.add(Personid.toString());
                   queue.add(FirstName);
                   queue.add(LastName);
                   queue.add(DateOfArrival);
                   queue.add(PassportNumber);
                   queue.add(PriorityLevel);
                   queue.add(PriorityNumber);

                   System.out.println(queue);
```

result:

```
 [218, Akhil, Chandran, 2020-02-21, KH1234567, High Priority, 3]
 [219, Emma, Sony, 2020-11-11, HJ73737377, Low Priority, 1]
 [220, Michele, Philip, 2021-10-22, HJ989898, Medium Priority, 2]
 [221, Zania, Zing, 2024-09-26, GH565656, Medium Priority, 2]
 [222, Pole, Mathew, 2020-04-14, HY212121, High Priority, 3]
 [223, Myra, Mary, 2020-03-04, GH6666666, High Priority, 3]
```

need to get:

```
  [218, Akhil, Chandran, 2020-02-21, KH1234567, High Priority, 3]
  [222, Pole, Mathew, 2020-04-14, HY212121, High Priority, 3]
  [223, Myra, Mary, 2020-03-04, GH6666666, High Priority, 3]
  [220, Michele, Philip, 2021-10-22, HJ989898, Medium Priority, 2]
  [221, Zania, Zing, 2024-09-26, GH565656, Medium Priority, 2]
  [219, Emma, Sony, 2020-11-11, HJ73737377, Low Priority, 1]
```

Comment: Then why are you using an ArrayList? And I see no attempt to actually sort the list, please post relevant code. Right now this looks like a request for us to write the code for you.

Comment: The code you posted will not produce the output you posted. Your output is an List of objects and your code is a list of String.

Comment: You can implement your own Comparator. Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {});